# Controls and parent touch in THorzScrollBox

Tags: android, listview, delphi, scroll, firemonkey

I have a `THorzScrollBox` with 3 `TLayout` controls inside it.

I put some code to make `HorzScrollBox1.AniCalculations.SetTargets` go to the layout I want based on my scroll and it was a success running.

But when I put `TListView` inside the `TLayout`,  I can't scroll it, because the `HitTest` of the `TListView` is enabled. I must disable it to scroll the `THorzScrollBox`, but if I do then the `TListView` can't scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the alFmxControl.apk demo of alcinoe (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) you will see that it's handle something similar, but instead of TlistView it's a Tabcontrol and vertScrollBox.

To resume the idea both TabControl and the VertScrollBox receive the mousemove event and as soon as you move you finger more on the left or right then the vertscrollbox is deactivated and only the tabcontrol receive futur mouse event, or as soon as you move your finger more on the up or down then it's the opposite, tabcontrol is deactivated and only the scrollbox receive the mouse event.

Mouse event are handled via CMGesture that as i remember don't care if a child controls catch the mouse event via it's hittest property

You can inspire from this code to see how to transpose it to your TListView

Comment: thanks, but where i can find full codes from ALFmxControls zeus? i only can download the apk file.

Comment: here: https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe you can download the full source code ...